# create multiple charts during runtime ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, charts, highcharts, runtime

I am fairly new to SSRS reporting. I have a table as below. The number of rows in the table may vary.

```
ID bigint
Name bigint
Value float


ID  Name    Value
1   100      1.47
1   110      1.52
2   100      1.46
2   130      1.40
2   170      1.44
2   190      1.38
```

I would like separate charts to be created at runtime; one for each distinct value of the ID field in the dataset.

E.g. for the above table there will be two charts in the report ideally in two pages.

First chart will have:

- x axis as Name 
  100, 110
- Y axis as Value
  1.47, 1.52

Second chart will have:

- x axis as Name 
  100, 130, 170, 190
- Y axis as Value
  1.46, 1.40, 1.44, 1.38

Comment: Can you let us know what you've tried already?

Comment: Hi I have tried the following with no luck! https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/76ee9ba0-ce95-4ad9-bcec-8947984f5eb3/creating-chartsgraphs-dynamically-in-ssrs-2008

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want a separate bar chart for each ID in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so, what you need to do is...

1. Create a **List** in your report
2. Group your list on the ID field of your dataset. This will have the affect of repeating the contents of the List for each distinct value that it finds (in your example table, it will the contents of the list for ID 1, then for ID 2)
3. Insert your bar chart into the List
4. Set the Category Groups to be your "Name" field
5. Set the Values to be the "Value" field from your Dataset

And I think that should do it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the steps. When I edit the group properties, I get the following exception. Aggregate functions cannot be used in group expressions.

Comment: Do you mean the group for the List? It shouldn't be grouped on an aggregate, just `=Fields!ID.Value` like in the below image:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/1o5SQ.png

Comment: Sorry. It was my fault. It shows multiple charts however all the Id. Basically I see 6 charts?

Comment: Are there 6 distinct ID's? That would cause there to be 6 different charts. If not I'm not sure - can you upload the RDL somewhere?

Comment: Nope. I have bundled up report solution file and the script to create table in sql onto onedrive.  https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=f2b90f129385d077&id=F2B90F129385D077%21257&Bsrc=Share&Bpub=SDX.SkyDrive&authkey=!Aim2CtaqiQM9mQ4

Comment: Any ideas.  Its summing the values is it?

Comment: Not sure at the minute I'm afraid. Having looked at your SQL script I would expect the report to produce 3 Graphs, since there are 3 distinct values in that table for the field "pulse"

Comment: I am not entirely sure too. I thought it would produce 3 graphs. How strange. I got it working with different set of data. I will bundle up the latest working version and upload onto onedrive soon. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: Ah! Wonderful. What was the problem? I was just replying to say I have no idea why it was repeating 6 times!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not sure. But I have to figure it out otherwise I wont be able to sleep. I am investigating.